# Do I need to create a new Postgres user for every new Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, postgresql-9.3, rails-postgresql

On my OS X machine, I have a working Rails app (4.2) with Postgres (9.3).

Now, to create a second Rails app, would I need to create a new pg user?

In my first app, no username is provided in `database.yml`

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: my_first_app_development
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Comment: you can create a pg user and use it against multiple projects by mentioning it in database.yml

Answer (score 2):

Short answer no. You can use one user for many databases if that user be owner of this database or has superuser role.

I prefer to use one user in local machine that have superuser privileges.

```
$> sudo -u postgres psql
postgres# CREATE ROLE my_user CREATEDB SUPERUSER;
postgres# ALTER ROLE my_user WITH LOGIN;
```

Now you can create database with `my_user` owner:

```
postgres# CREATE DATABASE my_database WITH OWNER my_user;
```

Or just create database with a `rake task` but before add username to `database.yml`:

```
database: my_first_app_development
username: my_user
```

from shell:

```
$> bundle exec rake db:create
```

This good only for local development environment for production create separate user with right privileges.